# How to load dwg file in SQL Server Spatial data type column?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, dwg

How can I load a `.dwg` file into a SQL Server spatial data type column directly from SQL Server Management Studio, without 3rd party software?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to convert it to a shapefile (.shp) and then use the GISinternals tools [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php)